# How to get more result using node-youtube getbyId() method

Tags: node.js, youtube-data-api

I am using node-youtube(data api) to get the result of youtube-saerch by id. When I write 
 `res.render('index',{data:(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))});` then I get two results. But when i write `res.render('index',{data:result});` then i get only when result. How can i get more results by simply writing   `res.render('index',{data:result});`
 rather than writing

```
   res.render('index',{data:(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))});
```

Here is the code of getbyId() metod.

```
var YouTube = require('youtube-node');

var youTube = new YouTube();
youTube.setKey('*************************');

youTube.getById('HcwTxRuq-uk', function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  else {
    res.render('index',{data:(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2))});
  }
});
```

I have also tried JSON.parse() method.
like this

```
var str=(JSON.stringify(result, null, 3));
var data=JSON.parse(str);
```

In str there are 3 results but in data there is only 1 result. why it return
one result. Also can i get 3 results using JSON.parse().

Comment: You only get exactly ONE video with getById function. Each video has unique id so you get no more than one video. Did you actually check what is the value of your "str". Your are passing three variables into stringify that's why there are 3 results but only one is video and other two are stringified null and 3

Comment: Actually, i am using this method to search the youtube videos. There are two methods first is the search by query and 2nd(this one) is search by id.Also it returns exactly 3 videos when the value is 3 it returns 2 videos when the value is 2. it depends upon the value of 1,2 or 3.but how can  i pass the value using json.pares().

Comment: The way you are using JSON.stringify is **WRONG** check the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify 
the 3rd argument you are passing into stringify function **"is used to insert white space into the output JSON string for readability purposes"** it has **nothing to do with the number of videos**

Comment: I'm having problem in using it. I want my script to wait till I get response from youtube. But it does not stop. Is there any way to wait for it to get response and then return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you want

Also notice there's **no need for JSON.stringify at all**

```
var YouTube = require('youtube-node');

var youTube = new YouTube();
youTube.setKey('************************************');

youTube.search('World War z Trailer', 2, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {

        // result should contain 2 videos with some info
        // to get more info use getById

        var videos = [];

        var video1 = result.items[0].id.videoId;
        var video2 = result.items[1].id.videoId;

        //get 1st video
        youTube.getById(video1, function(error, result) {
            if (!error) videos.push(result.items[0]);

            // get 2nd video
            youTube.getById(video2, function(error, result) {
                if (!error) videos.push(result.items[0]);

                //console.log(videos[0]);
                //console.log(videos[1]);
               res.render('index',{data:videos)});

            });

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly your question, but I think it could help you to see how I'm doing in one of my projects.

If your videos are in a playlist, you can fetch up to 50 videos at the same time and use the `pageToken` to fetch more if you want more videos from the playlist.

You can fetch the playlist like this :

```
/**
    * Return an array about the videos contained in the GEM-MECHANIC playlist (based on the selected language).
    *
    * @param $errorMessage String to return the error message.
    * @param $language Int language code for which we must fetch the video (default 1 = english)
    * @param $maxVideo Int maximum of video we must fetch with the request (<= 0 mean infinite, 5 if invalid)
    * @param $playList Int Playlist which want to fetch (Use PlayList class constants).
    *
    * @return Bidimensionnal Array
    */
    static public function getVideoList(&$errorMessage, $language = 1, $maxVideo = 0, $playList = PlayList::GEM_CAR){

        $errorMessage = "";

        $list = array();

        $gemPlayList = self::getPlayList($playList);

        if (array_key_exists($language, $gemPlayList)){

            if (!is_numeric($maxVideo) or $maxVideo < 0){

                $maxVideo = 5;
            }

            $list = self::fetchVideoList($errorMessage, $gemPlayList[$language], $maxVideo);
        }
        elseif(empty($gemPlayList)){

            $errorMessage = GeneralDbManager::getInstance()->getErrorMessage("GEM_MECHANIC_INVALID_PLAYLIST_ERR", "The selected playlist doesn't exists.");
        }
        else{

            $errorMessage = GeneralDbManager::getInstance()->getErrorMessage("GEM_MECHANIC_INVALID_LANGUAGE_ERR", 'The selected playlist do not contains videos for the language selected.');
        }

        return $list;
    }


    /**
    * Return an array about the videos contained in the GEM-MECHANIC playlist (based on the selected language).
    *
    * @param $errorMessage String to return the error message.
    * @param $playListId String id of the youtube playlist for which we want to fetch the video list.
    * @param $maxVideo Int maximum of video we must fetch with the request
    * @param $maxVideo Int number of videos with fetched so far.
    * @param $nextToken String to use to fetch more videos.
    *
    * @return Bidimensionnal Array
    */
    private static function fetchVideoList(&$errorMessage, $playListId, $maxVideo, $currentCount = 0, $nextToken = "", $currentList = array()){

        if ($currentCount < $maxVideo or $maxVideo === 0) {

            $result = abs($maxVideo - $currentCount);

            $param = array('playlistId' => $playListId);

            if ($result > 50 or $result === 0){

                $param['maxResults'] = 50;

                $result = 50;
            }
            else{

                $param['maxResults'] = $result;
            }

            if (!empty($nextToken)){

                $param['pageToken'] = $nextToken;   
            }

            try{

                $client = new Google_Client();

                $client->setDeveloperKey(self::$apiKey);

                $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

                $playList = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('contentDetails, snippet', $param);


                unset($youtube);

                unset($client);


                foreach($playList as $video){

                    $currentList[] = array('id' => $video['contentDetails']['videoId'], "title" => $video['snippet']['title'], "check" => 0);
                }


                $currentCount += $result;

                if (empty($errorMessage) and !is_null($playList['nextPageToken']) and $currentCount < $maxVideo){

                    self::fetchVideoList($errorMessage, $language, $maxVideo, $currentCount, $playList['nextPageToken'], $currentList); 
                }

                unset($playList);

            }
            catch (Google_Exception $exception) {

                ExceptionLogger::logException($exception);

                $errorMessage = GeneralDbManager::getInstance()->getErrorMessage("GEM_MECHANIC_CANT_FETCH_VIDEO_ERR", 'We are currently not able to fetch the video list from Youtube.');
            }
        }

        return $currentList;
    }
```

Comment: sorry,but in my case i get the more result using json.stringify() by passing the number 1,2,3 or more but i don't know how to pass this number using json.parese().